# Azure DevOps - compare master branch to master branch in the past

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

Is there an easy way to see changes in master compared to the master branch in the past?

I want to see all changes to a particular solution that have happened over the past 4 months. The view I get when I create a PR would be perfect, but as if I was creating a PR from master to master-4-months-ago.

Comment: Hi, does Josh's answer help you achieve what you want? Feel free to share your latest progress.

Comment: Josh's answer is helpful, I marked it as the answer. But what I want isn't a list of individual commits, I'd like to see all the changes for a file / all files for every commit from point A to point B.

Comment: @Dudeman3000 This question is still not marking an answer as accepted. What about the illustration for showing the actual **Compare** (read: diff) for a single file or for all files is not sufficient to your comment? [Single file diff for range of commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBETs.png) and [All file diff between tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTEB5.png) should give you what you want `"I'd like to see all the changes ..."`. If this isn't getting you where you need to be, would you consider updating your question with more detail? That would help others understand what you need. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies @JoshGust, I've marked your response as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## There are a couple ways:

### For a single file

Navigate to the file in the repo, select the compare tab, and apply the appropriate commit range.

[image]
[image]

### For all files

Use Tags.

Create a tag at the commit 4 months ago and a tag for HEAD.
[image]

Then compare them. This will give you a list of commits between them and allow you to show the diffs.

**The *DIRECTION* of the comparison matters for your results**

This feature uses a **similar concept** to executing `git log master..` from a branch that should be ahead of master. The result will be commits in the current branch that are not in master, whereas the reverse `git log ..master` shows commits that are in master that are not in the current branch.

This feature returns changes that are in the `"target"` tag that are not in the `compare` tag. Since we are looking at the tags on the same branch, setting the early tag `tagA` as the `compare` tag and comparing `tagB` to it, results are shown. However, setting the later commit `tagB` as the compare tag will not give results b/c there isn't anything in `tagB` that isn't also in `tagA`.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can just fiddle with the url:

```
https://dev.azure.com/[org]/[project-name]/_git/[repo-id]/ ...
branchCompare?baseVersion=[source-version]&targetVersion=[target-version]&_a=commits
```

Where `source-version` and `target-version` are one of:

- `GBxxxx` where xxxx is a branch name
- `GTxxxx` where xxxx is a tag name
- `GCxxxx` where xxxx is a commit sha1

You can get `org`, `project name` and `repo-id` from the url of any page clicking around your repo in Azure DevOps.