# Azure DevOps API SDK - Is there a route to get Pull Request difference in detail?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

When I'm looking at a PR in the browser, the line-by-line differences are returned from this API:

`dev.azure.com/myproject/_apis/Contribution/dataProviders/query/project/{projectId}`

With response containing this kind of data:

[image]

I'd like to get this same data via their API SDK.
There are some routes for Pull Request data in the `SourceControl.WebApi` but I don't find anything that shows line differences in detail, per line.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet)

Comment: Can I know where you want to make apply to? For extension? Or you are trying to develop a app which integrate with azure devops and get its data.

Comment: Sure, for custom metrics.