# Azure Devops Repos compare file between two branches

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, compare, azure-repos

I have a repository in Azure Repos. I have two branches "develop" and "abc". I have the same file (pom.xml) which exists in those 2 branches. How can I see the differences between branches for this file? I tried to use "Compare" option but it compares only between commits within the same branch.

[image]

Comment: Check this out- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-compare-files-between-branches/1398162?viewtype=all

Comment: @Arko this issue is closed and I do not see solution provided.

Comment: They gave the link under workaround- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533905/azure-devops-compare-two-commits-right-in-the-web-ui

Comment: @Arko those workarounds are either for comparing whole branches or commits.

Comment: If you use compare of two branches, it shows you the diff for all files that differ between them. You can drill down to view the diff for the specific file(s) that you are interested in, and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Azure Devops UI doesn't provide that feature.

I'm afraid you'll have to resort to other comparing tools.

Comment: seriously? that is such a basic functionality, how come its missing in such a mature project?

Comment: I agree. Bitbucket also doesn't feature it. My guess is this will be part of the next features these platforms will add.

Comment: Lets hope it will be included in next features as well. btw I  think I was using this functionality in GitLab so I was expecting to find something similiar in Azure Repos as well.

Answer (score 0):

To compare files in **different branches** in DevOps UI you can use Pull request, which is better than [branch compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60229869/14996050) as it shows conflict tab. You can check either `commit` or `conflict` tab.

[image]

Or you need **checkout the repo to local machine**, use compare tool to pick these two files for comparation.

If you would like this feature in DevOps, you can raise a user voice ticket via link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?space=21.

Comment: Thanks this is surely interesting workaround but I personally think it is an overkill to create a pull request every time you need to check differences for 1 file.

Comment: @fascynacja, there's no out-of-box solution to compare only file between different branches in DevOps, please raise a user voice ticket with the link above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have raised a ticket in Developer Community:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Devops-Repos-compare-file-between-/10510655

Comment: Nice! In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested that you [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!

Comment: but my question does not have an answer which solves my problem.